# Bluebird promises in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I have a chain of promises in nodejs. They look like this:

```
 codecommon.db.executeDbCommandAsync({
                'aggregate':'table1', 
                pipeline:[
                    {$match:{uid:uid}},
                    {$match :{timestamp:{$gt:start_week,$lt:end_week}}},
                    {$group:{_id:{"pageSession":"$pageSession"}, totalpersession:{$sum:1}, min:{$min:"$timestamp"}, max:{$max:"$timestamp"}}},
                    {$match:{totalpersession:{$gt:1}}},
                    {$project:{seconds:{$subtract:["$max","$min"]}}}
                ]
            })  .then(
    function(result) {
        dayspv = get_days(result[0].documents[0].result);
        totaldays = sum_days(dayspv,totaldays);         //vb interaction
        return common.db.executeDbCommandAsync({
                'aggregate':'table2', 
                pipeline:[
                    {$match:{uid:uid}},
                    {$match :{timestamp:{$gt:start_week,$lt:end_week}}},
                    {$group:{_id:{"pageSession":"$pageSession"}, totalpersession:{$sum:1}, min:{$min:"$timestamp"}, max:{$max:"$timestamp"}}},
                    {$match:{totalpersession:{$gt:1}}},
                    {$project:{seconds:{$subtract:["$max","$min"]}}}
                ]
            });     }) . then(      function(result) {
            days = get_days(result[0].documents[0].result);
            totaldays = sum_days(days,totaldays);
            //sm interaction            return common.db.executeDbCommandAsync({
                'aggregate':'table3', 
                pipeline:[
                    {$match:{uid:uid}},
                    {$match :{timestamp:{$gt:start_week,$lt:end_week}}},
                    {$group:{_id:{"session":"$session"}, totalpersession:{$sum:1}, min:{$min:"$timestamp"}, max:{$max:"$timestamp"}}},
                    {$match:{totalpersession:{$gt:1}}},
                    {$project:{seconds:{$subtract:["$max","$min"]}}}
                ]
            });

                }) .then( ...etc
```

Taking into account that in every promise i have same mongo query. I want to make a function like this:

```
var check_interaction = function(table, uid, start_week, end_week){

    return common.db.executeDbCommandAsync({
                'aggregate':'\'' + table + '\'', 
                pipeline:[
                    {$match:{uid:uid}},
                    {$match :{timestamp:{$gt:start_week,$lt:end_week}}},
                    {$group:{_id:{"session" :"$session" }, totalpersession:{$sum:1}, min:{$min:"$timestamp"}, max:{$max:"$timestamp"}}},
                    {$match:{totalpersession:{$gt:1}}},
                    {$project:{seconds:{$subtract:["$max","$min"]}}}
                ]
            });

};
```

and switch the promise chain to something like that:

```
check_interaction(...) .then( process some data
                             return another check_interaction(...);)
                       .then( process some data
                             return another check_interaction(...);)
                       .then(...etc
```

All mongoskin functions/queries are promisified, it dosen't throw an error, goes through whole chain(debugged with console logs), thou no data provided from one to another. Can someone help me?